# Returning an object, when it is empty GAE Endpoint

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

Is there any way that GAE parses a null object when using Endpoints. 
For example, if i return an array a = [1,2,3].
It will return

```
{a:[1,2,3]}
```

But if i return an array a = []

```
{}
```

That's what i get, there is no response in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your data into the *Bean*, you can define `ApiTransformer`, that will transform your entity into the desired output. So you can check in your transformer whether the array is empty and if so then you can transform it into the null or whatever you want. See documentation for [ApiTransformer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer).